# File name doesn't get cleared after form.$setPristine for a custom angular directive for file upload

Tags: angularjs, forms, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I am using `angular 1.5.8`. After following some resources, I got the file upload working. I had to create a custom directive for that.

**Directive**

```
//file-upload-model-directive.js
'use strict';

export default function (app) {

    app.directive('fileUploadModel', fileUploadModelDirective);

    function fileUploadModelDirective () {
        'ngInject';

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: linkFn,
            require: 'ngModel'
        };

        function linkFn (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          element.bind('change', function(event){
            var files = event.target.files;
            var file = files[0];

            ngModel.$setViewValue(file);
            scope.$apply();
          });

        }
    }
}
```

I am also using angular's `form`. And I have a "reset" button on this form. I want to clear all the form fields when clicked. And it happens with all form fields except `file`.

**View**

```
<form ng-submit="dataCtrl.upload(form)" name="form">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : form.file.$invalid && !form.file.$pristine}">
    <label>Select file</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" ng-model="dataCtrl.newUpload.csvFile" file-upload-model required/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : form.comment.$invalid && !form.comment.$pristine}">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="comment"
      ng-model="dataCtrl.newUpload.comment" required></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group pull-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Upload</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dataCtrl.reset(form)" ng-disabled="!form.$dirty">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**And the Controller**

```
'use strict';

function DataController($log, catalogCnst, requestSV, $http) {
  'ngInject';

  this.reset = function(form) {
    this.newUpload = {};
    // form.file.$setViewValue(null); // this didn't work either
    form.$setPristine()
  };

  this.upload = function(form) {
    // some code
  };
}
```

When "reset" is clicked, I see that

```
form.file.$pristine is false
form.file.$invalid is false
```

But I still see filename near the file upload element.

I also tried adding watch and handling event on the element in the directive

```
scope.$watch(attrs.fileUploadModel, function(value) {
  console.log('attrs.file');
});

element.on('$pristine', function() {
  console.log('destroy');
});
```

But they didn't get invoked.

How do I do this? Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clear `newUpload`, file input does not get cleared. You need to do this separately.

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/369x3gjj/):

Basically, I added to the directive `scope`:

```
scope: {
  model: '=ngModel'
},
```

... and `watch`:

```
scope.$watch('model', function(file) {
  if (!file) {
    element.val('');
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I wonder what was wrong with my $watch. Say, If I was watching attrs

Comment: `attrs.fileUploadModel` just refers to the `file-upload-model` attribute in the  `input` element. It is always an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using button tags, why not use input tags. This, in theory, might work.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" value="Upload">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="dataCtrl.reset(form)" ng-disabled="!form.$dirty" value="Reset">
```

Comment: This clears the filename. But reset doesn't set form.$invalid to true. So even after my form is reset, upload button is still active.